# Given $G$ is cyclic and $H \subset G$, is it true that $G/H$ is a cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am stuck on trying to find an element in $G/H = \{g + H | g \in G\}$ that will generate the whole set. My intuition tells me it is true since $G$ and $H$ are cyclic. I have a feeling that this direct approach of definition of a cyclic group is not the effective way to tackle this problem. Any advice appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If $G=\langle g\rangle$ then $gH$ generates $G/H$

Comment: This question has been asked many times and is easy to find by googling. You should try that before asking questions.

Comment: @verret I did in fact google it and must have missed your link (which was the only link from stack exchange related to this problem, asked 4 years ago). Thank you for the condescending remark.

Comment: You may consider my remark condescending, but due diligence before asking a question is actually site policy.

Comment: Yes I understand; however, there are ways to inform others without being condescending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g$ is a generator for $G$, $gH$ (the coset) **by definition** generates $G{/}H$, as $x \to xH$ is a surjective homomorphism.